# How can I display viewpager below a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I generated a swipe activity. The activity needs to have it's own layout with a view pager underneath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.mferreira.crm.recordSwipeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_item_view" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My only issue is at runtime the fragments are displayed inline with the layout itself at the top of the page rather than underneath it

Comment: post your entire layout file

Comment: @GokhanArik you want the content_item_view layout? The layout of the activity displaying that and the fragments is posted

Comment: That doesn't look right. AFAIK your layout has to have one root layout. Yours has two. Just copy paste entire file.

Comment: @GokhanArik sorry I posted it now, stack formatting was messing with it

Comment: Have you tried adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `content_item_view`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your issue is because the top-level `CoordinatorLayout` behaves like a `FrameLayout`, not a `LinearLayout`. If you want your `@layout/content_item_view` and your `ViewPager` not to be inline with each other, wrap them in a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/content_item_view" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I add that I lose the scrolling of the viewpager @Bryan

Comment: @AlexF11 Horizontal scrolling, vertical scrolling, or both?

Comment: When I wrap the layout and viewpager in a linear layout it forces everything underneath the toolbar. When I include the toolbar it all displays correctly but the viewpager isn't there at all.

Comment: @AlexF11 How big is the `content_item_view` layout? Is the height set to `match_parent`?

Comment: You're a genius. Set the height to wrap_content and it works. I'll have to wrap this in a scroll view in case it gets pushed too far down again.

Comment: @AlexF11 Haha, I try   Make sure it's a [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) if you want your `Toolbar` to scroll along with it.